# How can i get my While statement to correctly loop and break and at the same time input another option in java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am having a problem getting my code to loop with a while statement. I want it to be like when you input 1 in difficulty you get Beginner. Then it would ask if you want beginner. If not then you press 2. Then it would go back into the loop and ask you what difficulty you want. Then eventually break the loop.

The Beginner();, Intermediate();, and Hard(); is there to call something.

Also would it be possible to do option with strings instead? 
For example.

```
System.out.print("\nPlease choose your difficulty (1.Beginner, 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
Difficulty = option.next();
```

I initially wanted it to be where you could type out "Hard" and it would ask "You have chosen hard. Is this correct?"

```
public static void gameSetting() {
        String settings = null;
        int Difficulty = 0;
        int Beginner = 1;
        int Intermediate = 2;
        int Hard = 3;
        System.out.print("\nPlease choose your difficulty (1.Beginner, 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
        Difficulty = option.nextInt();
        while(true){if(Difficulty==1) {
            System.out.print("You have chosen Beginner. Is this correct?");
            System.out.println("\n1.Yes, 2.No");
            int choice = option.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                Beginner();
            }
            break;
        }
        if(Difficulty == 2) {
                System.out.print("\n\nYou have chosen Intermediate. Is this correct?");
                System.out.println("\n\n1.Yes, 2.No");
                int choice = option.nextInt();
                if(choice==1) {
                    Intermediate();
                }
                break;

            }
        System.out.print("\nPlease choose your difficulty (1.Beginner, 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
        Difficulty = option.nextInt();
        if(Difficulty == 3) {
            System.out.print("\n\nYou have chosen Hard. Is this correct?");
            System.out.println("\n\n1.Yes, 2.No");
            int choice = option.nextInt();
            if(choice==1) {
                Hard();
            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("\nPlease choose your difficulty (1.Beginner, 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
        Difficulty = option.nextInt();

}
    }
```

My Loop code that i'm trying to get to work ^

Comment: Move the `break`(s) into the `if` bodies. `if (choice == 1) { Beginner(); break; }` currently when `choice` is not one you still break. You also should only prompt for `Difficulty` once per iteration.

Comment: To capture string, you can use `nextLine`

Comment: Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, move the `break` statements into your `if` bodies and only prompt for `Difficulty` once per iteration. Also, your variable names deviate from Java standard naming conventions. `Difficulty` should be `difficulty`, and constants should be in all caps (and you *could* use the constants you have defined). Like,

```
public static void gameSetting() {
    final int BEGINNER = 1, INTERMEDIATE = 2, HARD = 3;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please choose your difficulty (1.Beginner,"
                    + " 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
        int difficulty = option.nextInt();
        if (difficulty == BEGINNER) {
            System.out.print("You have chosen Beginner. Is this correct?");
            System.out.println("\n1.Yes, 2.No");
            int choice = option.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                Beginner();
                break;
            }
        } else if (difficulty == INTERMEDIATE) {
            System.out.print("\n\nYou have chosen Intermediate. Is this correct?");
            System.out.println("\n\n1.Yes, 2.No");
            int choice = option.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                Intermediate();
                break;
            }
        } else if (difficulty == HARD) {
            System.out.print("\n\nYou have chosen Hard. Is this correct?");
            System.out.println("\n\n1.Yes, 2.No");
            int choice = option.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                Hard();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could refactor the common confirmation messages into another method. Like,

```
private static boolean confirmDifficulty(String difficulty) {
    System.out.printf("You have chosen %s. Is this correct?%n", difficulty);
    System.out.println("1.Yes, 2.No");
    return option.nextInt() == 1;
}
```

And then your code might look like

```
public static void gameSetting() {
    final int BEGINNER = 1, INTERMEDIATE = 2, HARD = 3;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please choose your difficulty (1.Beginner,"
                    + " 2.Intermediate, 3.Hard) ");
        int difficulty = option.nextInt();
        if (difficulty == BEGINNER) {
            if (confirmDifficulty("Beginner")) {
                Beginner();
                break;
            }
        } else if (difficulty == INTERMEDIATE) {
            if (confirmDifficulty("Intermediate")) {
                Intermediate();
                break;
            }
        } else if (difficulty == HARD) {
            if (confirmDifficulty("Hard")) {
                Hard();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```